# MP4 Video will NOT play in chrome if uploaded from Instagram Draft Folder on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, video, instagram, mp4

Ok Guys, this is a real real cazy one. Channel your inner nerd. I have tried, and failed (sad face)

So, simple enough. I allow users a "preview" of video content they have captured or uploaded to the system, before saving.

```
loadFilePost = function(event) {
  window.mediaPostData = event.target.files[0];
  if(window.mediaPostData) {
    startAVibe();
    var $source = $('#video_modal_here');
    $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    $source.parent()[0].load();
    $source.parent()[0].play();
  }
}
```

Now this works absolutely perfectly, except in one case, and one case only. If the video is from the instagram folder in your media gallery, the video will not play. The video will not even play in a chrome browser after its uploaded. If I manually download the file from the browser it plays fine, if I use safari, firefox or IE, it works fine, and I must re-instate that every other video works fine in the chrome browser EXCEPT for videos coming out of the instagram saved drafts folder. I swear, you can't make this stuff up. Someone please help. How can It work everywhere else but chrome?

Comment: Anyone? I'm begging lol

Comment: I think its something to do with the bitrate maybe